# Awk field values inside make file

Tags: bash, awk, makefile

I have a makefile, and I am trying to use awk in a one liner inside of it:

```
# makefile
...
SHELL := /bin/bash

my_rule:
    ls dir | awk -v path=$(current_dir) '{print path"/"$1}' > some_file
```

however, I can't seem to get make to drop the `$1` into awk.  How do I escape/access the field variables in awk, within the makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `$` to `$$` in makefile to make `awk` read it as correct field.

Comment: awesome, will do--internet got knocked out

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
# makefile

SHELL := /bin/bash

my_rule:
    ls dir | awk -v path=$(current_dir) '{print $$path"/"$$1}' > some_file
```